# Python Requests: set proxy only for specific domain

Tags: python, python-requests

Is there a native way in Python with the requests library to only use a proxy for a specific domain?

Like how you can mount HTTP Adapters, but with proxies, like the following example:

```
from requests import Session 
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter

s = Session()
s.mount("http://www.example.org", HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))
```

Comment: You can set up the proxy dictionary such that specific URLs use a particular proxy but you can't use wildcards (or similar) to restrict use to a domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a dictionary keyed on domains with proxies as associated values.

Let's assume you're interested in HTTP GET. Then you just write a wrapper around requests.get()

For example:

```
from requests import get as GET, packages as PACKAGES
from urllib.parse import urlparse as PARSE

PACKAGES.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS = 'ALL:@SECLEVEL=1'

DOMAINS = {
    'www.bbc.co.uk': 'http://115.144.101.200:10000'
}

def http_get(url):
    proxy = DOMAINS.get(PARSE(url).netloc)
    proxies = {url: proxy} if proxy is not None else None
    print(f'{proxies=}')
    return GET(url, proxies=proxies)


print(http_get('https://news.bbc.co.uk'))
print(http_get('https://www.bbc.co.uk'))
```

**Output:**

```
proxies=None
<Response [200]>
proxies={'https://www.bbc.co.uk': 'http://115.144.101.200:10000'}
<Response [200]>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is built-in support for origin-specific proxies in Requests:

Quoting [the documentation on proxies](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies):

> To give a proxy for a specific scheme and host, use the `scheme://hostname` form for the key (for `proxies`). This will match for any request to the given scheme and exact hostname.
>
> ```
> proxies = {'http://10.20.1.128': 'http://10.10.1.10:5323'}
> ```
>
> Note that proxy URLs must include the scheme.

Comment: Yeah the problem is that this won't work for different subdomains or even something like www vs no www.

Comment: Which wasn't a requirement in the original question.