# How to mount a custom adapter by domain (wildcarding subdomains) with python requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

This is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74991540/python-requests-set-proxy-only-for-specific-domain) but not quite the same.

There are some situations in which I need to supply default values for certain arguments like `verify` (e.g. a custom CA/SSL chain) for specific domains

```
from requests import Session 
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter

class MyHTTPAdapter(HTTPAdapter): ...

s = Session()
s.mount("http://www.example.org", MyHTTPAdapter())
```

so that not only would `www.example.org` be handled, but also other subdomains (including redirects) that we cannot determine ahead of time, due to lots of redirects. In this specific situation, we have an s3-like server which returns a lot of 307's to get to the right server that has the file we want to download. Imagine calling a `GET` to `download.example.org` which provides a `307` to `p06636710s64948.example.org` for us to download the file from, however we need the custom CA chain applied to the redirect too.

We don't have a way to deterministically know all the possible servers that could be redirected to (in some cases, a virtual machine is rapidly spun up just to serve this request that got made and comes with a dynamically generated name). How can we mount an adapter in such a way to automatically set `verify` without asking users to do it themselves via

```
s.get('.....', verify='/path/to/ca/chain')
```

at the top-level which propagates all the way through?

The best option I can think of is to do something similar to what's mentioned in this [github comment](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/2155#issuecomment-50771010) and use `partial.functools` to override `s.get` to check the URL and change `verify` as needed before passing it through.

Comment: how about `s.mount("http://", MyHTTPAdapter())`  `s.mount("https://", MyHTTPAdapter())`

Comment: adding the SSL cert to all http/https will break some other https calls we make to other domains (SSL verification error due to self-signed certs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only test with `verity = False` which works so hopefully your self-signed cert will go through.

```
import requests

class MyHttpAdapter(requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter):
    def cert_verify(self, conn, url, verify, cert):
        #or use regex...
        if ".example.org/" in url:  
            verify = '/path/to/cert'
        super(MyHttpAdapter, self).cert_verify(conn, url, verify, cert)

s = requests.Session() 
s.mount('https://', MyHttpAdapter())
s.get('https://www.google.com/')
s.get('https://download.example.org/')
```

Comment: This works. Only modification is that I used `urlib.parse.urlparse(url).netloc.endswith('example.org')` for the conditional, but the rest seems to be working. I did not realize adapters had a `cert_verify` override like this.